# kinit returns error salt type 3 unsupported on FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE install

Tags: freebsd, password, authentication, kerberos

When attempting to run kinit to log into a Kerberos V5 realm I get the following error on a default install FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE

kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: salt type 3 not supported

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any default etypes defined in your /etc/krb5.conf?

Comment: I do not have any default etypes configured in /etc/krb5.conf

Comment: Is it possible to debug what etypes the server supports from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

(Not a complete solution, as I don't know how to fix the problem, but this should at least give you an idea where to look.)

“Salt type” refers to the algorithm used to hash the password by the [`crypt`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crypt&sektion=3) function. The salt type is visible in the password hash (the second field of [`master.passwd`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=master.passwd&sektion=5)) which starts with the salt type between dollars (so `$3$…` in your case).

Salt type 3 under FreeBSD is an obsolete Windows hashing method, so it's surprising to see it here. I don't understand Kerberos well enough to know whether that value is coming from the client or the server.